# Angular ngMask is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have injected the ngMask dependency and linked ngMask.js but I'm getting an error in console like

```
ReferenceError: Â is not defined
```

May I know what would be the issue?

Comment: Is that a letter `A` or an `A` with a diacritic mark?!

Comment: The issue is that `Â` is not defined.

Comment: _Where_ are you getting that error from? Is it from the library or is it from code which you wrote?

Comment: yes, It is diacritic mark but where should I define this?